# Прерывание текущей анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Решил создать игру по типу agar.io. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Вот мой код:

```
<script>
var ball = $(".ball");
window.addEventListener("mousemove", moveBall);

function moveBall(e){
  var coorX = e.pageX,
      coorY = e.pageY;

ball.animate({
  'top': coorY+'px'
},1);

ball.animate({
  'left': coorX+'px'
},1);

}
</script>
```

Проблема: Когда водишь мышкой, анимация при смене координат меняется по выполнению прошлой команды (То есть, если я 3 раза проведу с верху вниз, то анимация не прервётся пока не выполнит прошлое действие)

Comment: Я вижу js и jquery, при чём здесь xcode?

Comment: Простите, изменил.

Comment: Может, поможет [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) для остановки текущей выполняемой анимации

```js
var ball = $(".ball");
window.addEventListener("mousemove", moveBall);

function moveBall(e) {
  var coorX = e.pageX,
    coorY = e.pageY;

  ball.stop().animate({
    'top': coorY + 'px',
    'left': coorX + 'px'
  }, 1);
}
```

```css
.ball {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ball"></div>
```